# setValuesForKeys resulting to this error: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key type

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

This is the first time that I will be attempting to use the method **setValuesForKeys** and for some reason, I keep stumbling upon the error as stated below:

> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key type.

I've gone through several related questions here but to no avail. Here's my code below:

```
class ResumeCategory: NSObject {

var name: String?
var resumes: [Resume]?

static func getJSON() {

    let urlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to get data from URL: ", error)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary

                print(json["categories"]!)

                var resumeCategories = [ResumeCategory]()

                for dict in json["categories"] as! [[String: Any]] {

                    let resumeCategory = ResumeCategory()
                    resumeCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
                    resumeCategories.append(resumeCategory)
                }

            } catch let error {
                print("Failed to parse server response: ", error)
            }

        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: In the affected class the key `type` is missing or the class does not inherit from `NSObject`. Basically the method `setValuesForKeys` is inappropriate in Swift. It requires classes inherited from `NSObject`. The `Codable` protocol in Swift 4 is much more suitable.

Comment: @vadian But the class is already inheriting from NSObject. I intended to switch to using Swift 4 decodable though. I just needed to know exactly what I was doing wrong here.

Comment: Once again: In the JSON there is a key `type` but there is no corresponding property in the class.

Comment: I get it now. Will try to resolve that. Thanks. @vadian